# Manhwa where the female lead gets pushed down the stairs by her husband and she's reborn. They hated each other and he looked badly injured

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, reincarnation

I can't remember where I started reading it, but all I remember is that it starts off with her looking distraught and her husband coming around, and they start fighting. He has a cane and an arm brace or sling and I'm pretty sure his face was burnt or covered. He pushes her down the stairs. She comes back to life before she ever married him and ends up meeting him to see that he didn't look like that before, and was nice, and that's all I remember.

Comment: Hi. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: I believe it was white or blonde

Answer (score 1):

***[The Redemption of Earl Nottingham](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-redemption-of-earl-nottingham)***.

> Is my cursed husband's fate up to me? Madelyn's husband Ian was left broken after the war, and in turn, made her life a living hell. Fleeing her doomed marriage, she meets a tragic end. But when she opens her eyes, she finds herself at 17 again. The war has yet to start, and Madelyn can still change her fate. But what about Ian?

Comment: Hi. Could you edit this answer to explain how _The Redemption of Earl Nottingham_ matches the OP's description? It'd help other users decide how likely it is to be the correct answer.